# r summary by group and within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summary

If this is my datatset, arranged by `Subject` and `Test`

```
ID    Subjects   Test   Score     Results
1     English    1      78        Pass
2     English    1      98        Pass    

2     English    2      81        Pass
3     English    2      81        Pass

2     English    3      15        Fail 
3     English    3      74        Pass

4     Physics    1      34        Fail
2     Physics    1      79        Pass

4     Physics    2      74        Fail
3     Physics    2      81        Pass   
3     Physics    2      81        Pass

4     Physics    3      48        Fail    
2     Physics    3      15        Fail
3     Physics    3      74        Pass
```

I am interested in creating summaries like this

```
           Test1                   Test2                  Test3
Subject    FailAverge   %Fail      FailAverge   %Fail     FailAverge   %Fail
English    0            0          0            0         15           50
Physics    34           50         74           33%       31.5         66
```

- The summaries grouped by Test attempt(1,2,3)
- Summaries for each subject
- During each test attempt, % failed and average score of those who failed during that attempt. For example during **Test attempt 3 & Physics**, Two students failed out of Three so %fail is (2/3)*100 and average score among those who failed is (48+15)/2

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took an attempt using tidyverse principles. To get that extact format you will probably need some table package (eg. GT) but the below gets you close.

I summarized the data into a new data frame then used the pivot wider to get the rows to columns and lastly did some minor tidying.

```
#recreate the table
df <- tribble(
~ID,    ~Subjects,   ~Test,   ~Score,     ~Results,
1,     "English",    1,      78,        "Pass",
2,     "English",    1,      98,        "Pass",    
2,     "English",    2,      81,        "Pass",
3,     "English",    2,      81,        "Pass",
2,     "English",    3,      15,        "Fail", 
3,     "English",    3,      74,        "Pass",
4,     "Physics",    1,      34,        "Fail",
2,     "Physics",    1,      79,        "Pass",
4,     "Physics",    2,      74,        "Fail",
3,     "Physics",    2,      81,        "Pass",   
3,     "Physics",    2,      81,        "Pass",
4,     "Physics",    3,      48,        "Fail",    
2,    "Physics",   3,      15,        "Fail",
3,     "Physics",    3,      74,        "Pass") 

#create table to summarize the grouped data
df_fail <- df %>% 
  group_by(Subjects,Test) %>% 
  summarize(FailAverage=mean(Score[Results=="Fail"]),
            Failper=mean(Results=="Fail",na.rm=TRUE))


#pivot wider the values, arrange the columns in order and then did some renaming
df_fail %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(Test),
                        values_from = c(FailAverage,Failper)) %>%
  relocate(Subjects,contains("1"),contains("2"),contains("3")) %>%
  rename_with(.cols = c(-Subjects),.fn = ~gsub("_", "_test", .x))
```

Comment: You could simplify `Failper` to `mean(Results=="Fail")`.

Comment: I think you also don't need the join, better to everything in one `summarise` call: `df %>%  group_by(Subjects,Test) %>% summarize(FailAverage = mean(Score[Results=="Fail"]), Failper = mean(Results=="Fail"))`. After that we can continue with `pivot_wider`.

Comment: Thanks @TimTeaFan I've updated the answer to reflect your comments. I was going down one path (individually filtering tables) before realizing that I could do it one step but kept the two table approach. Your suggested solution is more efficient.

Comment: @alejandro_hagan, thanks that is exactly what I was expecting.